# Perfect hashing for permutations

Tags: permutation, backtracking, perfect-hash

Consider the following list of permutations of {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,*,*,*} as generated with ordinary backtracking:

```
    Index  Permutation
    1.     0123456***
    2.     012345*6**
    3.     012345**6*
    4.     012345***6
    5.     0123465***
    ...
    60480. ***6543210
```

Is it there an O(1) function which, for any permutation gives back the permutation's index?

Comment: I would be interested in the motivation. (Trivial answer: build a hash table.)